# Excel Macro doesn't copy contents of rows

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro that compares 2 columns, each one from a different file, and gets every match into a third file together with some additional cells from one of the files.

Also, in the first 2 files have some editing on them so their cells with actual data start on the 4th and 2nd row of their respective columns so i used 2 different variable so my loops would start at these cells.

The thing is, even if my macro runs without errors it doesn't copy the data to the third file.

I have the following code:

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet, w3 As Worksheet
    Dim range1 As Range, range2 As Range

    Set w1 = Workbooks("Worksheet_Name1").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set w2 = Workbooks("Worksheet_Name2").Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set w3 = Workbooks("Worksheet_Name3").Worksheets("Sheet3")

    Set range1 = w1.Range("E4", w1.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set range2 = w2.Range("A2", w2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For Each c In range2
        rangeVar2 = c
        If rangeVar2 > 3 Then
            For Each n In range1
                rangeVar1 = n
                If rangeVar > 2 Then
                    If w1.Cells(n, "E").Value = w2.Cells(c, "A").Value Then
                        w3.Cells(c, "A").Value = w1.Cells(c, "E").Value
                        w3.Cells(c, "B").Value = w2.Cells(c, "A").Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next n
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: The code looks fine to me, although I prefer `For i = 1 to lastrow` loops instead of iterating through a pre-set range, I think gives a bit more readability. I will say, however, that some parts of your code are redudant - Why do you need `rangeVar2` and `rangeVar1` when your ranges are pre-set? Won't those always evaluate to `True`?

Comment: Add a MsgBox above `If w1.Cells(n, "E").Value = w2.Cells(c, "A").Value` that compares the values and manually check: `MsgBox "Comparing " & w1.Cells(n, "E").Value & " and " & w2.Cells(c, "A").Value & "..."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I re-wrote this for you and changed a few things. This could still be modified a bit but this should at least *work* for now.

The `rangeVar1` and `rangeVar2` were completely redundant, also preventing your code from running (I think). No need for those.

```
Sub ReWrite()
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet, w3 As Worksheet

Set w1 = Workbooks("Worksheet_Name1").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set w2 = Workbooks("Worksheet_Name2").Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set w3 = Workbooks("Worksheet_Name3").Worksheets("Sheet3")

Dim lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long, i As Long, j As Long

lastrow1 = w1.Cells(w1.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = w2.Cells(w2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 4 To lastrow1
    For j = 2 To lastrow2
        If w1.Range("E" & i).Value = w2.Range("A" & j).Value Then
            w3.Range("A" & j).Value = w1.Range("E" & i).Value
            w3.Range("B" & j).Value = w2.Range("A" & j).Value
            End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Now for whatever reason i am getting a Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range because it can't find the workbooks i want to compare.

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man Did you change the names in w1 w2 w3 back to what they actually are? I assumed you changed them for this example

Comment: Yes i changed them back to normal. The thing is one of my worskeets wasn't open so the macro wasn't able to find. SO no problem there, it was just me being a dummy. 
I ran your code and it doesn't show errors but it also isn't giving me any results, the worksheet just comes out empty, i guess i'll try to save each of the worsheet contents in different sheets to see if they are actually reading something. I'll give you the points anyways because technically the code runs normally.

Comment: Have you scrolled down on workbook 3 and checked to make sure there's no data down there? Because one issue I've noticed with your code is that it's printing values on workbook 3 on the same line as value `j`, which could be wayyy down on the worksheet. How many rows are you working with?

Comment: With a lot of rows actually. but i scrolled down and it didn't have any rows or cells with data. Maybe there ain't matching cases in these working sheets but i'll have to check for it anyways or create a test sheet with matching results.

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man Yeah this should be working, at this point I'd think that there are just no matches being made. Add `MsgBox "Got one!"` after the line `If w1.Range("E" & i).Value = w2.Range("A" & j).Value Then
` to see if the code is ever finding a match. At that point, we'd know it's matching, but where the data is being placed is still a mystery.